# How to adjust CSS width property for transition in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently having a problem with adjusting width property in javascript.

I want to adjust width of btnFocus class fit to childNodes(img file and text) so that CSS transition can be worked appropriately. However, getting width of btnFocus isn't working correctly. it just keep getting width value before childNodes is added or ends up with causing code error.

here are I'm intending to do

1. At first, hotspot class has no childNodes. when user clicks the class, click event adds data-content value(img file and text) inside hotspot class.
2. javascript gets an width of hotspot img file and text are added.
3. after that, width of hotspot widers smoothly to width value I got in step 2 with CSS transtion.

here are codes I'm working with

**treat.html**

```
<div id="clickBox">
            <a class="hotspot" data-content="Forehead <img src='/images/common file/logo2.png' class='hotLogo'>
              <span class='fontRed'> Deep</span>"></a>
            <a class="hotspot" data-content="Chin <img src='/images/common file/logo_purple.png' class='hotLogo'>
              <span class='fontPurple'> Volume</span>"></a>
          </div>
```

**treat.css**

```
#clickBox .hotspot {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
  background-image: url("/images/2.treat/rect.png");
  background-size: cover;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 0.3rem;
  opacity: 0.5;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 1s ease-in-out;
  transition-property: width, border-radius;
}

.hotspot>.hotLogo {
  width: 55px;
}
#clickBox .hotspot.btnFocus {
/* width gonna be changed in js file*/
  width: 1rem;
  height: auto;
  opacity: 0.8;
  border-radius: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: clip;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

**treat.js**

```
let hotspot = document.querySelectorAll(".hotspot");

hotspot.forEach(function (element) {
  element.addEventListener("click", function () {
    smallBtn(element);
  });
});

function smallBtn(element) {
  if (element.classList.contains("btnFocus")) {
    element.innerHTML = "";
    element.classList.toggle("btnFocus");
  } else {
    hotspot.forEach(function (element) {
      element.innerHTML = "";
      element.classList.remove("btnFocus");
    });
    let content = element.dataset["content"];
    // cause error at below
    let contentWidth = content.getBoundingClientRect().width;
    let btnFocus = document.querySelector("btnFocus");
    console.log("contentWidth : ",contentWidth);

    btnFocus.style.width = contentWidth;
    element.classList.add("btnFocus");
    element.innerHTML = content;
  }
}
```

Also I treid setProperty

```
element.style.setProperty("--contentWidth", contentWidth + "px");
```

and CSS variable but none of them worked.

What I need to know is contentWidth value to change btnFocus width.

My apologies for bad english. Hope you understand what I'm trying to tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update javascript code like this.

```
  let hotspot = document.querySelectorAll(".hotspot");

  hotspot.forEach(function (element) {
    element.addEventListener("click", function () {
      smallBtn(element);
    });
  });

  function smallBtn(element) {
    if (element.classList.contains("btnFocus")) {
      element.innerHTML = "";
      element.classList.toggle("btnFocus");
      element.style.width = '1rem';
    } else {
      hotspot.forEach(function (element) {
        element.innerHTML = "";
        element.classList.remove("btnFocus");
      });
      let content = element.dataset["content"];
      // cause error at below
      let contentWidth = getDomWidthFromHtmlString(content);
      element.classList.add("btnFocus");
      let btnFocus = document.querySelector(".btnFocus");
      console.log("contentWidth : ", contentWidth);
      console.log(btnFocus)
      btnFocus.style.width = contentWidth;
      element.innerHTML = content;
    }
  }

  function getDomWidthFromHtmlString(htmlString) {
    const tempElement = document.createElement("a");
    tempElement.innerHTML = htmlString;
    document.body.appendChild(tempElement);
    const domWidth = tempElement.offsetWidth;
    document.body.removeChild(tempElement);
    return domWidth;
  }
```

Please check getDomWidthFromHTMLString function

Comment: I edited a bit and was able to solve the problem with your code. Thank you!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).